# custom FTP program

Tags: c#, sockets, ftp

I have an FTP tool created with Visual studio 2008  / C# / .Net 3.5 framework.

The tool connects with 5 different FTP servers and downloads files without any issue. However, the same tool when it connects with one other FTP server (xxx), the connection fails. I checked firewall exception on both client and server sides and this IP is not filtered.  But, I can connect to xxx server via FileZilla / Internet explorer / windows explorer with the same credentials on port 21 and it let me to see and download files. Here is the below code to make FTP connection.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void Connect(string server, string user, string pass)
{
    main_sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        main_ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(server).AddressList[0], 21);  // returning correct IP
    }
    catch 
    {
        main_ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses(server)[0], 21);   
    }

    try
    {
        main_sock.Connect(main_ipEndPoint); // failing at this line. 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return;
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 123.192.122.1XX:21.

error code : 10065

Comment: Try sniffing the network with netcat or similar to see if the packets are been sent, if arrives to destination, etc..

Comment: If your using the same code to connect on all the FTP servers, connecting from the same location AND you can connect to filezilla from the same machine, I would quadruple check your credentials and that your calling the correct variables. otherwise it doesn't seem to make sense. I don't see you using the username and password in your code.

Comment: sounds like a credentials issue to me

Answer (score 0):

Error 10065 is not a credentials issue. It is a TCP protocol error. It usually means the host is not reachable. It occurs BEFORE the connection is made (before credentials can even be exchanged). Perhaps it is a timeout or firewall issue.

Can you verify that the IP address you use to connect (i.e. main_ipEndPoint) matches the one which the other FTP Clients get?  You should be able to see it in the FTP Client log.  Or perhaps you can enter the IP address directly into FileZilla (etc) and see if it can connect.

Comment: You are correct. the error occurred before the credentials were passed. I tried with the exact host, user name, password in filezilla and it worked. So there is no possibility of entering a wrong IP.